# iBatis to MyBatis migration efforts?

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I am using iBatis-2.3.4.726 in my production application. I want to migrate my production application to use MyBatis.

What points i need to consider while migration process?

Is there any configuration changes or MyBatis supports iBatis configuration as deprecated commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before using [migration guide mentioned by Satish](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/DocUpgrade3) ([new repo link](https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis2mybatis) / [wiki](https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis2mybatis/wiki)), make sure that you've read **all the comments**, especially the last one that list which changes have to be done **manually** after using converter:

> - `<procedure>` is deprecated in mybatis. Converter is changing this to `<update>`. This will create problems where we need result set from procedure call. So manually updated with `<select>`.

- Dynamic query part mentioned inside `<dynamic>` tag are not converted by tool
- Both `#` and `$` can be escaped by doubling in iBatis. This is not required in mybatis.
- `typeAlias` should be defined in `sql-map-config` instead of mapper itself.
- When result map with `groupBy` changed into mybatis style using `collection`, `id` property is not set properly by the converter.
- `jdbcType="INT"` is not recognized in mybatis. Updated to `"INTEGER"`
- `nullValue` in `resultMap` deprecated, we need to update query with `ISNULL` expression.

What I'd like to add is that converter seems to **drop `timeout` parameter** that could be present in `<procedure>` tag in iBatis. Make sure to copy all occurences to the generated XML.

Answer (score 4):

The migration process is very easy, i got my answer from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/DocUpgrade3)

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis2mybatis in the list of repos?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool on the [Github](https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis2mybatis), three steps to finish conversion.

1. make sure you have install *Apache ant*.
2. download code , and copy your ibatis files to the folder *source*
3. go to the root directory of the code and run *ant*

Note conversion may fail ! I got message like: *Sorry, I can`t migrate  WHERE
        See console output for further details*.
Hope this helps